# Make PHP Click Link On Same PAge Or Process A Form

Tags: php

Is there any php code i can use to click a link or process a form on the page the php is on?

Im building a redirect script and what i need to do is use php to move user to next page, its mandatory that php has to be used html doesnt work. In it i have a self submit forum but it doesnt work how i load the script. Is there a way i can use php code to submit it? or remove it and put a link there then use php to click that link?

This is the code below:

```
if ($_GET['ref_spoof'] != NULL) 
{
    $offer = urldecode($_GET['ref_spoof']);
    $p1 = strpos ($offer, '?') + 1;
    $url_par = substr ($offer , $p1);
    $paryval = split ('&', $url_par);
    $p = array();
    foreach ($paryval as $value) 
    {
        $p[] = split ('=',$value);
    }
    //header('Location: '.$offer.'') ;
    print 
    '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$("#mylink").click()</script>
    <a href="'.$offer.'" id="mylink">Index Page</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">$("#mylink").click()</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("myLink").click();</script>


    <form action="'.$offer.'" method="get" id="myform">
    ';
    foreach ($p as $value) 
    {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$value[0].'" value="'.$value[1].'">';

    }
    echo '</form><script language="JavaScript"> document.getElementById(\'myform\').submit();</script></body></html>';

}
```

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: i simply want the use php on my page to etheir submit the form or click a link.

Comment: I don't think PHP can do that, and I'm not sure why you'd ever need it to. You'll have to use JavaScript or something.

Comment: im loading php like <img src="http://site.com/pxl.php?i=1" height="1" width="1" /> and any html or forms or scripts in the php dont work for some reason only html.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to make this too complicated.
You're loading a page that submits a form using GET.

Is there any reason you can't use

```
       header("Location : ".$offer."?".http_build_query($p));
```

http_build_query being a function to generate an URL string from an array. Assuming $p is the array containing all form fieldnames+values.

example of http_build_query:

```
      $data = array('foo'=>'bar',
          'baz'=>'boom',
          'cow'=>'milk',
          'php'=>'hypertext processor');

    echo http_build_query($data);
    will result in:
    foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
```

Comment: If i go directly like that the referrer will be the same i want like a form submission to happen and submit my form.